# Mongo DB with C# - document added regardless of transaction

Tags: c#, mongodb, transactions, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to test the newly supported transactions in Mongo DB with a simple example I wrote.
I'm using Mongo DB version 4.0.5 with driver version 2.8.1.
It's only a primary instance with no shards/replicas.

I must be missing something basic in the following code.
I create a Mongo client, session & database, then start a transaction, add a document and abort the transaction. After this code, I expect nothing to change in the database, but the document is added. When debugging I can also see the document right after the `InsertOne()` by using Robo 3T (Mongo client GUI).

Any idea what am I missing?

```
        var client =  new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var session = client.StartSession();
        var database = session.Client.GetDatabase("myDatabase", new MongoDatabaseSettings
        {
            GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard,
            ReadPreference = ReadPreference.Primary,
            WriteConcern = new WriteConcern(1, 
                new MongoDB.Driver.Optional<TimeSpan?>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))),

        });

        var entities = database.GetCollection<MyEntity>("test");            

        session.StartTransaction();

        // After this line I can already see the document in the db collection using Mongo client GUI (Robo 3T), although I expect not to see it until committing
        entities.InsertOne(new MyEntity { Name =  "Entity" });

        // This does not have any effect
        session.AbortTransaction();
```

**Edit:**

It's possible to run MongoDB as a 1-node replica set, although I'm not sure what's the difference between a standalone and a 1-node replica set.
See my post below.

In any case, to use the started transaction the insertion code must receive the session as a parameter:

```
entities.InsertOne(session, new MyEntity { Name = "Entity" });
```

With these 2 change now the transaction works.

Comment: A bit of shameless advertising: If you don't feel like passing around the session object everywhere, JohnKnoop.MongoRepository provides an abstraction that automatically enlists with the current transaction: https://github.com/johnknoop/MongoRepository#transactions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is inherently a property of MongoDB itself. (More [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/multi-document-transactions) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/#transactions))

> Transactions are only available in a replica set setup

**Why isnt it available for standalone instances?**

*With subdocuments and arrays, document databases (MongoDB) allow related data to be unified hierarchically inside a single data structure. The document can be updated with an atomic operation, giving it the same data integrity guarantees as a multi-table transaction in a relational database.*

Comment: Wow, that's really over simplified reasoning. It seems they are practically saying that the design is forced to contain a single collection in order to use transactions, or rather transaction-like behavior. Obviously this constraint doesn't fit many applications, including mine.

Comment: The answer here is incorrect. There is no relation between MongoDB topology and data modelling (one collection or multi collections). The transaction is not available in standalone because it requires `oplog` to maintain strong consistency within a cluster. Technically you can run a standalone MongoDB with oplog (replica set with one node), although this is not recommended for production as you don't have redundancy. I would suggest to watch the engineering videos on https://www.mongodb.com/transactions to understand the behind-the-scene.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, although not sure what the consequences are, maybe someone can point it out:
It seems it's possible to use Mongo DB as a 1-node replica set (instead of a standalone) by simply adding the following in the mongod.cfg file:

```
replication:
   replSetName: rs1
```

Also, thanks to the following link the code should use the correct overload of `InsertOne()` which receives the session as the first parameter (see the edit on the original post):

[multiple document transaction not working in c# using mongodb 4.08 community server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869556/multiple-document-transaction-not-working-in-c-sharp-using-mongodb-4-08-communit)